# Programmatically set source database in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am running Apache Superset on AWS-ECS to facilitate a connection directly with our RDS. This connection works, but has to be configured manually.

Is there a way to programmatically configure source databases with Apache Superset?

I have tried setting `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`, but that is only for the Superset back-end configuration and settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superset has an [API](https://superset.apache.org/docs/api/), so you can create/update/delete databases via HTTP requests. Authorization is non-trivial, since you need login first to get a CSRF token and store cookies:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from yarl import URL

superset_url = URL('https://superset.example.org/')

session = requests.Session()

# get CSRF token
response = session.get(superset_url / "login/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
csrf_token = soup.find("input", {"id": "csrf_token"})["value"]

# get cookies
session.post(
    superset_url / "login/",
    data=dict(username=username, password=password, csrf_token=csrf_token),
)

# create database
database = {
    "database_name": "my db",
    "sqlalchemy_uri": "gsheets://",
    ...
}
session.post(
    superset_url / "api/v1/database/",
    json=database,
    headers={"X-CSRFToken": csrf_token},
)
```